# How to restore backup from another server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to restore a backup as follows:

```
   Server sqlServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(banco, user, senha));
   Restore dbRestore = new Restore() { Database = "a" + "" + txtBancoNuvem.Text.Trim(), Action = RestoreActionType.Database, ReplaceDatabase = true, NoRecovery = false };
   dbRestore.Devices.AddDevice($@"{path}\DataBase\BackupNuvem.bak", DeviceType.File);  
   dbRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Operating System Error 3 (The system can not find the path specified.).
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

The backup was done on a client machine and I am trying to restore it to a server machine. I believe that you are giving this error.
How do I solve this?

Comment: The error says your path is wrong, check again if is ti right.

Comment: What is the exact value of `$@"{path}\DataBase\BackupNuvem.bak`? Is that path accessible **from the machine running the above code**? Is it accessible from the DB Server?

Comment: The server does not have access to this path

Comment: That sounds suspiciously similar to `(The system can not find the path specified.).`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot run a back up on one server and a restore on another server. So if your path is C:/.../... then this will not work.

You must either copy over the file from source server to target server or ensure the path is a network path and access is granted in order to restore.

Comment: That misses my fear, so I'll have to upload the backup via network and create a destination folder like that path.

Comment: So long as the actual backup file is accessible from "another server" you can absolutely restore the file. The key is that the target server (and the service account of the database engine) must have access and the correct permissions.

Comment: That's what I put in my answer? "ensure the path is a network path and access is granted in order to restore."